# Generating content with Content_for in Haml between Html5 Elements in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, haml

I'm trying to generate dynamic content in my views.

in my application.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title YieldUsage
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
    = yield :head
    = yield :scripts
    = yield :name_section
```

and my helper is like;

```
def name_section_form
    content_for :name_section do
      label_tag(@post.name)
    end
  end
```

and my view;

```
%article
  = name_section_form
```

But it renders;

```
<body>
    <article>

    </article>


    <label for="asfd">Asfd</label>


</body>
```

Why is it happening? Bug or something? Any ideas?

Thanks.
Çağdaş.

Comment: I want to put label into article not after.

Answer (score 0):

Your view gets dumped into the `yield`. The method sets the content for a specific `yield`. Remove the `content_for` in your helper.

Comment: This works but maybe i wont put name_section to another layout. How can i figure this out?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you must have the `content_for` set sometimes, use a different helper method perhaps.